# Has anyone successfully used customMapStyle?

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

I'm trying to add custom style to map 
using **customMapStyle** but it is not working at all.

I've given it a **json array** as described in the documentation.

Anyone who has used it before, kindly help

**Here the json array:**

```
  mapStyle = [
    {
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "color": "#f5f5f5"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "elementType": "labels.icon",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "visibility": "off"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "color": "#616161"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "color": "#f5f5f5"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "administrative.land_parcel",
        "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "color": "#bdbdbd"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "poi",
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "color": "#eeeeee"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "poi",
        "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "color": "#757575"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "poi.park",
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "color": "#e5e5e5"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "poi.park",
        "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "color": "#9e9e9e"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "road",
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "color": "#ffffff"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "road.arterial",
        "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "color": "#757575"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "road.highway",
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "color": "#dadada"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "road.highway",
        "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "color": "#616161"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "road.local",
        "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "color": "#9e9e9e"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "transit.line",
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "color": "#e5e5e5"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "transit.station",
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "color": "#eeeeee"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "water",
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "color": "#c9c9c9"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "water",
        "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "color": "#9e9e9e"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I'm using this style in the  object like:
customMapStyle={mapStyle}

Comment: Should work. Can you update your question and add the code? the map component and the array

Comment: Have a look at it again, thank you